# Google Drive API: how to find files *not* shared with me?

Tags: google-drive-api

I'm trying to get a list of all the files that I have in the root folder of my Google Drive, excluding those shared with me... and yet Google Drive keeps giving me both the files in my root folder and the shared ones.

I am using this search query (Python code):

```
results = service.files().list(
   q="(name contains 'zip' or name contains 'gz') and 'root' in parents and 'me' in owners", fields="files(id, name, parents, owners)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])

print('Files:')
for item in items:
   print(u'{0}   {1}   {2}'.format(item['name'], item['owners'], item['parents']))
```

Looking at the docs, it seems that I'm doing everything right:

- I am using `'root' in parents`, to include only the files on the root folder.
- I am using `'me' in owners`, to include only my files and not those shared with me. (I got this parameter from https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client/issues/595, which seems to explain it as "intended behaviour" and suggests that workaround).

And yet, in the list of files I get back, I have stuff like this:

```
backup_2020-04-15-1033.zip   [{'kind': 'drive#user', 'displayName': 'OTHER USER'S NAME', 'me': False, 'permissionId': 'XXXXXXXXXX', 'emailAddress': 'otheruser@gmail.com'}]   ['{FOLDER ID OBSCURED']
```

This is one of the shared files; notice the `'me': False` there. Also, although I obscured the parent folder, it's different than the ID of my root folder. In other words: this file should have not been returned?

Is this a Google Drive bug? How can I search only for my files then?

Comment: `q="'YOUR EMAIL' in owners"` should be enough - unless you were made the owner of the file that is shared with you.

Comment: That worked, somehow. If you want to post it as an answer so that I can accept it...

Comment: Are you using a service account?

Comment: In Google Drive, you mean? No; it's just an individual account, nothing "enterprise" or fancy.

Comment: I meant to run your Python code. I am asking because `'root' in parents` won't work as intended when running the code with a service account.

Comment: I don't think so. I don't pretend to understand anything about the Google Cloud ecosystem, but I just logged into my console to have a look, and I don't have any account listed in "Service accounts" in my project, so I don't think so.

Comment: I should mention that I'm just learning Python, and I took the code from Google's quickstart (https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) and adapted it for my purposes; the authentication part in my code is pretty much the same as in the link.

Comment: Don't worry, if you are not sure either you are using a service account - probably you don't. May I ask you either you are using Drive API v3 or v2?

Comment: I'm using API V3.